# VBA Word Macro selecting inserted shape

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wish a simple VBA macro that inserts a picture then changes its height and width.  It works first time run.  The user, however, can add multiple pictures by running the macro more than once and my problem is that the macro inserts the next image but then resizes an image already on the document rather than the one just inserted.  I would have assumed that the .count would return the last image (i.e. the one jsut inserted)  It appears that the 'Set myImage line' doesn't reference the just inserted image.

Any help welcome.  Code below.

Greg

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture Anchor:=Selection.Range, FileName:= _
    "c:\mydir\carp3d.tif", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
' get last inserted image
Set myImage = ActiveDocument.Shapes(ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count)
myImage.Select
myImage.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
myImage.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
myImage.Height = 180#
myImage.Width = 124.55
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Shapes.AddPicture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shapes.addpicture) returns a `Shape` object that you should capture:

```
Set myImage = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(....)

myImage.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
' and so on
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I didn't know that syntax for AddPicture could return an object.  Worked perfect!

Comment: You don't need `myImage.Select` or two of `myImage.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue`. Furthermore, having locked the aspect ratio, you only need to set the height *or* the width, not both.,